# Schedule a container with docker swarm using gpu memory as a constraint

Tags: docker, gpu, nvidia, docker-swarm

Is it possible to schedule containers with docker swarm to nodes with a certain amount of gpu memory?

Eg, If I need to schedule a container with 5gb of gpu memory, how do I get swarm to not schedule the container until a node with sufficient gpu memory becomes available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of 1.12.x with Docker Swarm - the only way I can think of to accomplish something like this would be the following:

- From a manager node, label all the nodes that meet your requirements via the docker node update command:

  - `docker node update --label-add gpu-5g node-1`
- Then when you create your service use the constraint parameter to limit the service to run on the target machines

  - `docker service create ...--constraint 'node.labels == gpu-5g'`

If you need to have the run-time remaining available memory then perhaps a combination of containers to orchestrate the setting of labels.  A service container that runs on all of your GPU machines that report the current available memory and another on your manager node(s) to set the labels.

I'll be watching this question as it is an interesting one. It will be interesting to read how you end up solving this.

Comment: Gotten some feedback that mesos/marathon supports this, I'm looking into that, if that's not an option, I'll probably implement a version of the above, having a service container update node labels with the available gpu and using that as the constraint